# Angle-resolved photoemission spectral (ARPES) function from band Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, spectroscopy

I am trying to derive spectral function for a band Hamiltonian. I am using http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0306084 as a prototype reference. I do not understand how the coherence factors $u_k$ and $v_k$ enter in Eq. 5.

I do understand that $[u_k,v_k]^T$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $E_k^+$ but I fail to obtain how it enters spectral function $A(\omega,k)$. According to me $A(\omega,k)$ is related to the imaginary part of the Green's function $G(\omega,k) = ((\omega+i\eta)I - H)^{-1}$ where $\eta$ is infinitesimal. This formalism yields a $2\times 2$ matrix for $A(\omega,k)$, and not in the form provided in Eq. 5 in the paper. Could I obtain an explanation as to what am I missing.